# Set ivar value from category

Tags: objective-c, categories, ivar

I use a specific API, which has some class, for example `ClassA`.

`ClassA` has a property `importantProperty`,  ivar = `_importantProperty`, setter = `setImportantProperty`

What I need is actually to handle in debug when is property is changed, and what values are set to this property and print the stacktrace.

I can not inherit this class and override this method in my case, because it has defined class.

So I created a debug category, which overrides `setImportantProperty` method and now I can handle the stacktrace and values changes, but this method makes original method unreachable, and ivar value can not be changed. Is there any way to change this ivar?

Here is my method:

```
@implementation ClassA (Test)

-(void) setImportantProperty:(id) newValue {

    NSLog(@"%@, %@", newValue, [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
}

@end
```

So the question is there any way to implement such code `_importantProperty = newValue` in my method or are there any other ways to use in my case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sounds like you are searching for method swizzeling. http://darkdust.net/writings/objective-c/method-swizzling

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want a breakpoint?

Comment: How can i set a breakpoint to a method, which is in third party framework?

Comment: "Add symbolic breakpoint" in Xcode will let you put breakpoints on code that you don't have the source for.

Comment: As you said I tried to use symbolic breakpoint. When application stopped at breakpoint I was unable to see any values and stacktrace, just UIApplicationMain and current method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @vikingosegundo suggested, you could use method swizzling:

```
#import "ClassA+Test.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h> // Needed for method swizzling

@implementation ClassA(Test)

-(void) swizzled_setImportantProperty:(id) newValue {
    [self swizzled_setImportantProperty: newValue]; //it is NOT an endless recursion.
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", newValue, [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
}

+(void)load
{
    Method original, swizzled;
    original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(setImportantProperty:));
    swizzled = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(swizzled_setImportantProperty:)); //UPDATE: missed a column here, sorry!
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);
}

@end
```

Here we declare a new method `swizzled_setImportantProperty:`, and at runtime we swap it's implementation with `setImportantProperty:` implementation. So that when we call `setImportantProperty:` in code, the implementation for `swizzled_setImportantProperty` will be called and vice versa.

That's why when we call `swizzled_setImportantProperty:` inside the `swizzled_setImportantProperty:` implementation, it won't call an endless recursion, because `setImportantProperty:` implementation will be called. Just what we need.

**UPDATE:** Since overriding a `+load` method might cause problems if it have already been implemented (or if might be implemented in the future by the library creators), there is a better option suggested by @JoshCaswell :

```
#import "ClassA+Test.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h> // Needed for method swizzling

@implementation ClassA(Test)

-(void) swizzled_setImportantProperty:(id) newValue {
    [self swizzled_setImportantProperty: newValue]; //it is NOT an endless recursion.
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", newValue, [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
}

@end

void swizzleSetImportantProperty(void) __attribute__((constructor))
{
    Method original, swizzled;
    original = class_getInstanceMethod([ClassA class], @selector(setImportantProperty:));
    swizzled = class_getInstanceMethod([ClassA class], @selector(swizzled_setImportantProperty:)); //UPDATE: missed a column here, sorry!
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);
}
```

Comment: `load` is a potentially problematic choice here; being in a category, it will clobber an existing implementation on the class (just as the setter was clobbered). A constructor function might be a better idea.

Comment: Good point. I'll extend my answer. But I have to understand it first. I think that `+load` is a good choice if the class doesn't have it's own implementation. As for the constructor function, in this case we'll hide a constructor function, won't we? Do you mean `init`? In this case there might be several `init`s. And we should ensure that we exchange implementations only once (it's not a big problem, but we should keep it in mind).

Comment: No, I mean a function, not a method: `void swizzleSetImportantProperty(void) __attribute__((constructor)){ /* Swizzle */ }` See [GCC function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#constructor). In this case, since the implementation of the original class is not under our control, we don't know if `+load` is now implemented or will be in the future.

Comment: Nice trick :) Thank you. But will it work under Clang? As far as I remember, Apple's GCC is just a wrapper for Clang. Unfortunately, I don't have an opportunity to test it right now.

Comment: Sure thing. Yes, Clang supports it (and many other GCC-introduced extensions).

Comment: @JoshCaswell, thanks for the information! I will update my answer in a few hours to include your advices!

Comment: @JoshCaswell, unfortunately, the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) says that `constructor`, `destructor`, `constructor (priority)`, `destructor (priority)` are not currently implemented for Objective-C. May be I misunderstood something?

Comment: Well, that's the GCC docs, not Clang, and it's wrong anyways. Constructors did work in ObjC compiled by GCC; maybe Apple added them?

Comment: That's possible. I tested it now (finally), and it worked. I added it to my answer. It works as expected, but I'd be grateful if you checked it. Thank you for your time and patience :) It's been a long discussion, but I'm glad I learned something new from this question :)
@George, please, have a look at the updated version. thanks to Josh Caswell, It should be safer :)